# Populate new field when query documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have two schemas (using mongoose) like below:

```
var PostSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    content: String,
    likes: [{
        type: String,
        ref: 'User'
    }],
    ...
 })

 var UserSchema = new Schema({
     name: String,
     pinnedPosts: [{
         type: String,
         ref: 'Post'
     }],
     ...
  })
```

Now I want to get all posts with two new populated fields: isLiked and isPinned depend on the auth state. If the user hasn't signed in (auth is null) then all these two fields are false. If user has signed in and had liked the post, isLiked is true... Can I do it when I query the post?

Comment: what is `isLiked` and `isPinned`? It is not defined in your schema, Please post full schema.

Comment: Yes. It's not a part of the schema. isLiked and isPinned are two new fields I want to add to the response and it depends on the auth state of the request.